# SELECT LAST and FORELAST Values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I want to make a SELECT command, which selects the last and forelast value of my table in my database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM beitrag WHERE beitrag_id=101 OR beitrag_id=102";
```

At the moment I am only selecting it manually.

Comment: order by and limit 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `order by` and the `limit` clauses, like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM beitrag ORDER BY beitrage_id DESC LIMIT 2;";
```

Basically, we `order by` the id in `descending` order so that the highest one is the first, and we select only two elements (`limit`), so first "last" and "forelast".